# getting final column after comparing 4 columns using np.where()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

using np.where i am able to get 4 columns match1,match2,match3 and match4.Final column MATCHED has to be updated based on the values of match 1,match2,match3 and match4.if all 4 are yes then i have to update MATCHED as 'Yes' if any 3 out of 4 are yes then also 'Yes' is to be updated.Else No.

```
final_data = final_data.copy()
final_data['Match1'] = np.where(final_data['PROCESSOR_sub_column'] == final_data['PROCESSOR_Title'] , 'Yes', 'No')
final_data['Match2'] = np.where( final_data['RAM'] == final_data['RAM_Title'] , 'Yes', 'No')
final_data['Match3'] = np.where( final_data['Storage'] == final_data['STORAGE_Title'] , 'Yes', 'No')
final_data['Match4'] = np.where( final_data['Storage Type'] == final_data['STORAGE_TYPE_Title'] , 'Yes', 'No')

 if (final_data['Match1']&final_data['Match2']&final_data['Match3']&final_data['Match4'] == 'Yes'):

 final_data[Matched] = 'Yes'
```

*attaching the data already generated as screenshot* :[data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbiZZ.png)

i also tried to get the column Matched directly using np.where() , but i was not successful to check four conditions at the same time. also i don't know whst i should pass as X.y in np.where(,x,y) while using 4 conditions.

apologies if this question is repeat, i have tried my level best to read all previous posts about related topic.

Comment: @TimRoberts can you please suggest something.
i have decided to do 1) concanating the 4 columns 2) defing dict with triple yes and 4 times yes. 3) map the dictionary on concanated column and then create new final column.
But i don't know what i have to write in dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare all 4 columns for `Yes`, then count `True`s by sum per rows and compare if greater or equal by `3` by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html):

```
mask = df[['Match1','Match2','Match3','Match4']].eq('Yes').sum(axis=1).ge(3)
final_data['Matched'] = np.where(mask, 'Yes', 'No')
```

Another solution without helper columns id compare filtered DataFrames:

```
np.random.seed(2022)

c=['PROCESSOR_sub_column','RAM','Storage','Storage Type','PROCESSOR_Title',
   'RAM_Title','STORAGE_Title','STORAGE_TYPE_Title']
final_data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2, size=(10,8)), columns=c)
```

---

```
df1 = final_data[['PROCESSOR_sub_column','RAM','Storage','Storage Type']]
df2 = final_data[['PROCESSOR_Title','RAM_Title','STORAGE_Title','STORAGE_TYPE_Title']]
mask = df1.eq(df2.to_numpy()).sum(axis=1).ge(3)

final_data['Matched'] = np.where(mask, 'Yes', 'No')
print (final_data)
   PROCESSOR_sub_column  RAM  Storage  Storage Type  PROCESSOR_Title  \
0                     1    0        1             0                1   
1                     0    0        0             0                1   
2                     1    1        0             0                0   
3                     0    0        0             1                0   
4                     0    1        0             0                1   
5                     1    1        1             1                0   
6                     0    1        0             1                1   
7                     0    1        1             0                0   
8                     1    1        1             1                1   
9                     1    1        0             0                0   

   RAM_Title  STORAGE_Title  STORAGE_TYPE_Title Matched  
0          1              0                   1      No  
1          1              1                   1      No  
2          1              0                   1      No  
3          0              0                   1     Yes  
4          1              1                   1      No  
5          0              0                   0      No  
6          0              0                   0      No  
7          1              0                   1      No  
8          1              0                   1     Yes  
9          0              1                   0      No
```

Comment: thank you so much. thank you thank you than you...thanks a ton..
axis = 1 is for column but what is .ge for? if you can explain please.